# SharePoint online document Publish feature not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

The document publishing feature is not working as it was a few days ago.  Something has changed, does anyone know if and how this can be fixed?  This is what happens now:

- Right-click on a document, select More, then Publish
- Comments box is displayed, enter the comments and click publish
- A Publish button appears in the toolbar at the top
- Click on the Publish button
- The document is published and the version goes to the next major version number
- Click on version properties, the comments aren't displayed

The publish button at the top toolbar is new, the comments were previously visible in the version properties window.

Can anyone please help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue in my modern SharePoint Online site, but it's normal to publish in the classic SharePoint Online site. Try it in the classic SharePoint Online site.